# Invalid comparison in RegionPlot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot something like this:

```
RegionPlot[0 < (.5*a2 - .25*a1)/(a2 - a1) < 1 && 0 < a1 < a2 < 1, {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}]
```

The above code yields an error message (it tries to use 1/0 in the inequality). I can solve the problem by simply starting the plot at an arbitrarily low value of `a2`. My question is: is there a more "elegant" way of doing that? I would expect the inequality `0 < a1 < a2 < 1` to take care of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when you have `a && b` then `b` is not evaluated if `a` already returned `False`. Using this, the incredibly easy answer is

```
RegionPlot[
 0 < a1 < a2 < 1 && 0 < (.5*a2 - .25*a1)/(a2 - a1) < 1, 
 {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Well that would be simpler.... +1

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is simply the *printing* of the error messages you can suppress them with `Quiet`:

```
RegionPlot[
  Quiet[0 < (.5*a2 - .25*a1)/(a2 - a1) < 1 && 0 < a1 < a2 < 1],
  {a1, 0, 1},
  {a2, 0, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could also define a function that prevents this condition:

```
f[a1_, a2_] /; a1 == a2 := False

f[a1_, a2_] := 0 < (.5*a2 - .25*a1)/(a2 - a1) < 1 && 0 < a1 < a2 < 1

RegionPlot[
  f[a1, a2],
  {a1, 0, 1},
  {a2, 0, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]